# Change of web.config does not force dot net core application to be restarted

Tags: .net-core, web-config, application-restart

I am trying to restart my ASP.net Core application and for this purpose I'm changing the modification date of `Web.config`. As I expected it should force my application to be restarted but surprisingly it doesn't make any changes.
I did this modification by `File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(path, DateTime.UtcNow);`

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: @AminMozhgani, mac os and I use visual studio for mac

Comment: Web.config would not be useful for asp.net core applications unless your application is hosted on IIS. i think for the chagnes to be reflected you need to make your changes in appsettings.json

Comment: @user3785553, I did but unfortunately your advise does not work

Comment: Try this! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36121999/how-to-restart-asp-net-core-app-programmatically

Comment: @John, I try use this source but my version of .net core is deferent. I use .net core 2.1 and in this version IWebHelper.Run() method has not any parameters.

Comment: @alirezakhosravi Try keeping configurations in `appsettings.json` itself.