# Stop all running threads in a .net core server

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-core, threadpool

I have a `asp net core` server and i  was wondering if there is any way in which one can send a `request` by which it would announce the server to to terminate all other requests (that are waiting to be processed or are under processing ) ? I do not want to kill the server `process`...i just want to  clear both the request `queue` and the current tasks.

Is there any mechanism in the framework by which you could do that?
I have looked in the `ThreadPool` but it seems it does not expose the current running threads.

My approach would be to safely terminate them if there is such a mechanism.

Comment: Try to check [How to restart asp.net core app programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36121999/how-to-restart-asp-net-core-app-programmatically)

Comment: How would this help you? 
And what response should new incoming requests get then?

Comment: I do not care about the incoming requests.The thing is that i want to be able to provide a fresh start for the server (fresh start, without killing the root process)